# How to compare a nested array and return the value that are true

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have 2 nested array that I like to compare each other and return all the values in array 1 and array 2 are same. I tried to use `array1.include(array2)` but it didn't work.

```
let arry1 = [['B0844PGXJR', '7'],
['B085H4C8Z6', '1'],
['B087RS4RWL', '7'],
['B088LKDK3V', '4']] ;


let arry2= [['B0844PGXJR', '6'],
['B085H4C8Z6', '1'],
['B087RS4RWL', '7'],
['B088LKDR3V', '2']] ;
```

Output :

```
Result =  [ ['B085H4C8Z6', '1'],
['B087RS4RWL', '7'] ];
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) takes the [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) value or the object reference, like arrays and checks the same value or reference. By having different arrays with same content, you have different object references.

---

You could take a `Set` with stringified arrays and filter the second array with other stringified arrays.

```js
const
    array1 = [['B0844PGXJR', '7'], ['B085H4C8Z6', '1'], ['B087RS4RWL', '7'], ['B088LKDK3V', '4']],
    array2 = [['B0844PGXJR', '6'], ['B085H4C8Z6', '1'], ['B087RS4RWL', '7'], ['B088LKDR3V', '2']],
    set1 = new Set(array1.map(a => JSON.stringify(a))),
    common = array2.filter(a => set1.has(JSON.stringify(a)));

console.log(common);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using reduce that way you can keep track of a list of the values from the other list.

```
  let arry1 = [['B0844PGXJR', '7'],
['B085H4C8Z6', '1'],
['B087RS4RWL', '7'],
['B088LKDK3V', '4']] ;


let arry2= [['B0844PGXJR', '6'],
['B085H4C8Z6', '1'],
['B087RS4RWL', '7'],
['B088LKDR3V', '2']] ;



const duplicateValues = arry2.reduce((accumulated, current) => {

    const mappedKeys = arry1.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const key = curr.join('+');
        return {
            ...acc,
            [key]: true
        }
    }, {});
    const currKey = current.join('+');
    if (mappedKeys[currKeys]) {
        accumulated.duplicated.push(current);
    }
    return accumulated;
}, {
    duplicated: []
});

const duplicate = duplicateValues.duplicated;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the position of these elements will remain the same, you could do something like this (if you can't use sets from @Nina's answer):

Codepen: https://codepen.io/koiralakiran1/pen/RwoGNeN?editors=0011

```js
let arry1 = [['B0844PGXJR', '7'],
['B085H4C8Z6', '1'],
['B087RS4RWL', '7'],
['B088LKDK3V', '4']] ;


let arry2= [['B0844PGXJR', '6'],
['B085H4C8Z6', '1'],
['B087RS4RWL', '7'],
['B088LKDR3V', '2']] ;

let arr1str = arry1.map(i => JSON.stringify(i));
let arr2str = arry2.map(i => JSON.stringify(i));

let filtered = arr1str.filter(i => arr2str.includes(i))
  .map(i => JSON.parse(i));

console.log(filtered);
```